# I can't seem to build my android application when I'm signing it

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, sign

I can build the application when it's not signed but every time I try to sign Android Studio says something along the lines of

> "ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.cardview-v7:27.1.1"

I've checked [this](https://mvnrepository.com) and verified it exists but it doesn't seem to work, it gives other dependency issues if I try to fix it.

"My `build.gradle` (app)"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.org.cetma.llanellistandard"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven 
Central
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'

    //Add Library
    implementation 'com.android.support.cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


}
```

I want it to sign the application so I can make sure it still works.

Below is an example of the error I get:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.cardview-v7:27.1.1:
>       Affected Modules: app

Comment: There is a . after support, try com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

double dots are missing from your card view dependency use this -

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

> implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.0 is giving me issues now.   ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app